# How to make xPath for ul li a href tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-lists

I am working on this project were I need to verify that each item in list is loaded on page. However I am a bit confused how to create the xpath as the text is inside an  tag.

I first need need get the element and then assert if that item is displayed. The below first line works however assertion gives an error.

```
    WebElement costRequest = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Cost')]"));
    Assert.assertEquals(true, costRequest.isDisplayed());
    log.info("Verify cost request");
```

[image: inspected elements]

Answer (score 0):

You should use expected conditions - wait for the element to be visible instead of what you are doing now since `driver.findElement` returns the web element at the moment the element exists, but still not completed so it's not yet displayed.
So do something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Cost')]")));
WebElement costRequest = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Cost')]"));
Assert.assertEquals(true, costRequest.isDisplayed());
    log.info("Verify cost request");
```

Comment: this still not working for me, I suspect the xpath im doing is incorrect.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is there multiple `a` elements with "Cost" text? Maybe some delay is missing?